# How to pipe grep output to paste input?

Tags: bash

I basically want to take the line that is under the word "LOAD" in filename1, and make it the second column in a new file, where the first column comes from filename2. (This is being done inside a loop, but I think that's irrelevant.)

So if I have

```
grep -A 1 LOAD filename1 >> temp
paste filename2 temp >> filename3
rm temp
```

Is there a way to do that in one command, with no temp file? Something like

```
grep -A 1 LOAD filename1 | paste filename2 "grep output" >> filename3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use **process substitution** instead of using a temporary file:

```
paste filename2 <(grep -A 1 LOAD filename1) >> filename3
```

Comment: On old paste (paste 8.4 on CentOS6.5), I had to use the `-s` flag. It worked with pipe (@dermen answer) or process subsitution

Answer (score 5):

You can use '-' to represent the input from the pipe

```
grep -A 1 LOAD filename1.txt | paste filename2.txt - >> filename3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -A 1 LOAD filename1.txt  | paste filename2.txt /dev/stdin >> filename3.txt
```